# mobius transformation form $M= B(0,1)\setminus\overline{B(1,\sqrt2)}$ to a sector.

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

I know that the intersections of the two circles need to be sent to $0$ and $\infty$ in order to get a sector $S = \{x+iy: x>0,0<y<x\}$

The intersections of the two balls were i and -i. So i thought i would do the following:

$$i \rightarrow 0$$

$$-i \rightarrow \infty$$

$$-1 \rightarrow 1$$

this created the following mobiustransformation:

$$g(z) = \frac{z-i}{iz-1}.$$

the main problem is that i don't know where the other boundary-line of M is going. i tried filling in the value $z = 1-\sqrt{2}$, but i didn't succeed to find the correct solution. With this solution i can determine the angle of the sector and see which sector is the image of my function.

(The sector will have an scharp angle because the angles in the intersectionpoints are sharp, but what is the angle?)

Kees Til

Comment: This seems fine to me.  Why do you think this is wrong?  (The angle is the angle between the tangent lines at the point of intersection.)

Comment: i don;t think it's wrong, the problem is that i can't seem to find the exact angle :)

Comment: The tangent to a circle at a point is orthogonal to the radius ending in that point. What is the angle between the two radii of the circles ending in $i$?